# What does this Verilogger Pro error mean?

Tags: verilog

I got an error while programming in Verilogger Pro:

> error: maximum allowable lines in
>   evaluation version exceeded

What does this mean?

Comment: If I had to go out on a limb I would say, you're using an evaluation version of Verilogger pro.... and that evaluation has a line limit on it, so you have to buy the actual software to continue writing in it.

Comment: i m a student, i cant buy the software from net. i searched free version a lot but all have some problem. its CD is also not available in my area. Do u know any site from where i can get this?????

Comment: @Shaded - your comment would make a good answer...

Comment: Warez requests are not welcome on SO.

Comment: There are free and open source Verilog simulators.  Try verilator.

Comment: @ Pekka: my question is not about ware, its about an error tht i got during programming

Answer (score 1):

You can get a free 6 month license for the full version of VeriLogger from their web site that doesn't have any limitations. Go to http://www.syncad.com/syn_down.htm.